# What conditions must be met to make f(x) = a^x mod N periodic but not constant?

Tags: number-theory, quantum-computation

The renowned quantum algorithm Shor's Algorithm relies on the periodicity of the function $f(x)=a^x mod N$. The a, x, and N are all positive integers.

By observation, we know the function is constant for some a and N. For example, $6^x mod 15 = 6$ for all positive x. In other words, $6^x mod 15$ is a constant function. So, which a and N can be used to guarantee the function is not constant. Any formulas or theorems?

By the way, could you please help prove or disprove $6^x mod 15$ is indeed 6 for all positive x?

I am just a programmer and not very good at number theory.

Comment: $6^1\equiv 6\mod 15 $. Induct on $x$ for $6^x$. For example, $6^{x+1}=6\cdot 6^x\equiv 6\cdot 6\equiv 6\mod 15$.

Comment: $6^x$ is constant $\bmod 3\cdot 5$ because $6\equiv 0\pmod 3$ and $6\equiv 1\pmod 5$, and $0^x$ and $1 ^x$ are clearly constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a^x\bmod N$ is constant if and only if $a^2\equiv a\bmod N$ which is to say if and only if $a^2-a$ is a multiple of $N$. In all other cases, the function is not constant.

Comment: Very neat. Thanks. Is that a known theorem or a quick solution out of your brilliant mind in such a short time? If it is the former, would you please point me to a few websites to learn how to prove that mathematically? You've just piqued my curiosity. I tried each of the $a$ values to 1000. It is so true and convenient from the point of  view of a programmer:-)

Comment: Mind not so much brilliant as experienced and well-versed in techniques of intro Number Theory.